# How to calculate a composite score from correlations in a meta-analysis

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis on safety culture (predictor) and safety performance (outcome). In some studies that I am coding, they presented the correlations between the subscales of safety culture and safety performance, without providing the correlation between the overall score of safety culture and safety performance.

For example:

[image]

What is the best way to calculate the overall safety culture score so that I can figure out its correlation with safety performance?

If it helps, I am calculating the effect size using Hunter and Schmidt's method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as an answer since I do not have enough reputation points to post a comment. Your answer is in the book of Hunter and Schmidt (2014). Several examples are discussed in the book on how to deal with the situation you describe in your question. I do not have the book with me at the moment, so I cannot provide you a page number. However, searching the index of the book will definitely bring you to the right page.

Schmidt, F. L., & Hunter, J. E. (2014). Methods of meta-analysis: Correcting error and bias in research findings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had a look at the book, and it is suggested that the "correlations should be averaged and the average could be contributed as the one value representing the study" (p. 430 in the 2nd edition). However, I consulted other sources which argue that, correlations should not be averaged without transforming to Fisher's z first, then back-transforming to Pearson r. 

The problem however, is that Hunter and Schmidt also discourage the transformation of r to z.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed no consensus about whether you should transform your correlations to Fisher's z and then back-transforming to Pearson r. Ralf Schulze compared in his book different meta-analysis methods that use correlation coefficients (also with transforming to Fisher's z) [(link to amazon)](https://www.amazon.com/Meta-Analysis-Comparision-Approaches-Ralf-Schulze-ebook/dp/B00CDM4AH2/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1469082464&sr=1-2&keywords=meta-analysis+ralf+schulze#navbar). Maybe this is useful for you.