# Can you combine effects from both the composite and domain levels of questionnaires in a meta-analysis?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, meta-analysis, independence

First time posting here.

I am collaborating on a meta-analysis investigating the association between fatigue (in a specific clinical population) and cognition. I have done a few meta's before so I am at an intermediate level at conducting them however I am not able to find clarification to this question.

For studies we wish to include, some studies only report effects at a composite level (e.g., overall fatigue), some studies only report effects at the subdomain level (e.g., physical fatigue, cognitive fatigue), and some studies report both.

We are planning to conduct a multi-variate meta-analysis to account for dependencies arising from multiple effects from each sample however this does not, to my knowledge, clarify to me if it is still permissible to combine both composite and sub-domain scores form a study in a meta-analysis.

All thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Best wishes,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, yes, one can do this. However, I would not include subdomain level results and the composite result from the same study, since most 'composites' are just sum scores or means based on the subdomains and hence this is redundant. I would still code the result type (i.e., composite versus subdomain or even split the subdomains into subtypes if this can be done meaningfully across studies).

Since you also tagged this with `correlation`, you could also consider computing composite correlations for studies that only report subdomain level information if you want to 'standardize' the types of correlations you are meta-analyzing (but this will require information about the correlation among the subdomains). See [How to calculate a composite score from correlations in a meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/224703/1934) for a question/answer related to this.

Comment: Wolfgang, thank you for your helpful response.I will consider your suggestion to compute composites. The clarification that subdomains and composites can be included is appreciated.